# boxplot the data of the y-axis of a scatter plot using matlab

Tags: matlab, boxplot, scatter

What I basically want to do is to have boxplots for one data set on a scatter plot using Matlab.
We can do the scatter plot with `scatter(X, Y)` and instead of the points corresponding to `Y`, I would like to have boxplots.
Something like `scatter(X, (boxplot(Y))` - which of course does not work.

Have been searching high and low but could not find a relevant answer, or even something similar.

The scatter-points from the left-hand side have to be replaced with box plots as on the right:

[image: example]

Comment: In addition to @macduff - can you provide some background on what kind of information you want to visualize with the "additional dimension" (for the lack of a better term)?

Comment: I have some moisture values pertaining to 25 locations in a matrix, each column containing about 45 readings. I also have a single column (or a row) of moisture data that are assumed to be 'true' values and I would like to see how the match is, between the two sets of values. To make the scatter plot, I obtained the mean from the 45by25 matrix. However, I wish to see how the spread of the 45by25 is, on the same scatter plot and so tried to do a boxplot for that part.
Hope I am making sense explaining my problem.
Thank you very much

Comment: Ranmalee: Are you looking for something [like this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/10/07/box-plot-scatter-plot/)?

Comment: No, not really. Imagine a scatter plot, the limit of both X and Y axes at 0-0.5, with the Tan 45 line. If the X-axis has 0.20 m3/m3 for the first point, and the Y-axis has 0.30 m3/m3. Then we can have the point at (0.20, 0.30). Instead of one value for the Y-axis, I have 45 values. I want to do a boxplot for these 45 values, but located at 0.20 m3/m3 on the X-axis. Essentially, it IS a scatter plot, but showing the distribution of data on the Y-axis, mean, whiskers, outliers and all. 
Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show an example figure of what you mean?

Comment: I am unable to post images, as per the error I get saying that I need at least 10 reputations to do so. I am so sorry but is there an alternative way of adding an image? Thank you very much!

Comment: you can post the image somewhere else and just post a link here. someone with more reputation will edit the question for you.

Comment: The first image is the scatter plot that I currently have and the second image is what I want to have. The points have been replaced with boxplots, but located at the exact point on the X-axis as it needs to be.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20263082/Plots.png
Thank you