# boxplot the data on y-azis of scatter plot using R or ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, boxplot

[boxplot the data of the y-axis of a scatter plot using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356734/boxplot-the-data-of-the-y-axis-of-a-scatter-plot-using-matlab)

I'd like to create plot like in the question above:  use y-axis as quantitative scale for box plot, while x axis is another quantitative value.  How can I do this in R, or preferably in ggplot2?

Comment: A reproducible example could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What have you tried? `with(mtcars, qplot(x = cyl, y = hp, group = cyl, geom = 'boxplot'))` seems to work just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `group` to the variable assuming discrete values:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(col1=rexp(10), col2=rep(1:2, each=5))
ggplot(dat, aes(y=col1, x=col2, group=col2)) + geom_boxplot()
```

If there is none, then make one yourself :D

```
dat <- data.frame(col1=rexp(100), col2=rexp(100))
nxbins <- 3
dat$col3 <- cut(dat$col2, nxbins)
levels(dat$col3) <- with(dat, tapply(col2, col3, mean))
dat$col3 <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$col3))
ggplot(dat, aes(y=col1, x=col3, group=col3)) + geom_boxplot()
```

P.S.
Of course, a reproducible example prepared by you would be the best, instead of my shameful guesswork...

Comment: Thank you for answering my dumb question, this seems what I need.

Comment: Well thank *you* for giving me the opportunity to feel useful